# Django blog, up-down voting feature using github source

Tags: python, django, voting-system

I'm trying to include a youtube like up and down voting feature for my blog. I have used `pip install django-updown` to install [this](https://github.com/weluse/django-updown/blob/master/README.rst) to my project. I have followed all the instructions there.
I have included `updown` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, included `rating = RatingField()` to my `models.py` file and also included the `url` as described. But, the problem is, I can't see the voting system in my blog? I'm guessing it is something to do with the template file since nothing has been mentioned about it. 
I have the following commenting form in my template and would like the up-down vote to be shown before this. Can anyone help me out? Thanks :)

```
<div class="comment_form">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% get_comment_form for object as form %}
.....
{% else %}
<p>Please log in to leave a comment.</p>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Maybe there is a problem with my `urls.py` file?
This is the url for my individual blog post:

```
url(r'^book/(?P<pk>\d+)$', BookDetail.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
```

Following the documentation mentioned in the source documentation, I included:

```
url(r'^book/(?P<object_id>\d+)/rate/(?P<score>[\d\-]+)$', AddRatingFromModel(), {
'app_label': 'bookBlog',
'model': 'Book',
'field_name': 'rating',
name="book_rating"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [django-updown github](https://github.com/weluse/django-updown):

```
To submit a vote just go to video/<id>/rate/(1|-1). 
If you allowed users to change they're vote, they can do it with the same url.
```

Try following that URL directly and check if your votes are being added or not. If it is working, i guess you could just set some links to that view or something (or send some ajax requests).